# Should we burninate the [flutter-widget] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

The tag [flutter-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter-widget) has more than 200 questions with no usage guidance or tag wiki. The questions associated with this tag are generally no worse than any [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) question without it, but it appears to me that its primary usage is to fill out the tag list on questions.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It does somewhat describe the contents of a question, but it does so ambiguously. The lack of any usage guidance or information on the tag makes it difficult to understand what this tag actually means.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, this tag does appear to be on-topic for SO.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No it does not. Nearly everything in flutter is a widget and adding this tag does not tell me anything more about the question than just the [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) tag does.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes, it essentially means the same thing in all contexts because it has "flutter" in the tag, but it's unclear what that meaning is.

---

While I believe that this tag adds very little, if it is not the consensus of the community to burninate, it at least needs usage guidance added to the tag so that it is not used so randomly.

Comment: I always wonder how can the concept of a tag be on topic and the concept itself be ambiguous (adj. Of doubtful or uncertain nature; wanting clearness or definiteness; difficult to comprehend or distinguish; indistinct; obscure.).

Comment: @Braiam The tag has flutter in the name and asking about flutter is definitely on-topic, but it's unclear when this tag is supposed to be used and I don't believe there's a need for the tag in the first place.

Comment: Would a merge with [flutter] be the easier path here?

Comment: @Machavity Perhaps. I'm not familiar enough with the different actions that can be taken for tags. A merge would replace all instances of [flutter-widget] with [flutter] right?

Comment: Correct. It also creates a synonym, which prevents recreation of the tag

Comment: @Machavity I think a merge would be appropriate.

Comment: I checked and there's only 4 questions not also tagged [flutter]. If we do this, it will have minimal impact

Comment: @ChristopherMoore again, is either "of doubtful or uncertain nature" or it's unambiguous and on topic. You can't pick and choose which words represent the topic. The whole flutter widget is on topic or it's ambiguous.

Comment: @Machavity that particular issue is now resolved.

Comment: @Braiam I suppose that's technically true. It's definitely ambiguous so we can't definitively say that it's on-topic, but it is *probably* on-topic. That doesn't change that there should be some action taken with the tag however.

Comment: I disagree with this proposal. While flutter has been marketed as "Everything's a widget", there are actually many parts of flutter development that are not related to widgets such as business logic, platform code and ffi, compilation targets, compilation modes, performance and observatory, testing. These are just a few off the top of my head. It is unsurprising that only four flutter-widget questions are not also tagged with flutter. flutter-widget is a subset of flutter with more specificity. It certainly does add useful information and a narrower scope to the question.

Comment: @Stephen I have thought about that. However, there is no usage guidance for this tag and it's unclear what this tag should be used for. People are adding the tag to questions that simply have the word "widget" in them. What does this tag tell me about the question I'm about to read?

Comment: Merge and make a synonym.

Comment: @Stephen You should post that as an answer for voting (which is how we decide things like this)

Answer (score 10):

In Flutter everything is a widget, since there is already the `flutter` tag then the `flutter-widget` tag is not needed.

> I disagree with this proposal. While flutter has been marketed as "Everything's a widget", there are actually many parts of flutter development that are not related to widgets such as business logic, platform code and ffi, compilation targets, compilation modes, performance and observatory, testing. These are just a few off the top of my head. It is unsurprising that only four flutter-widget questions are not also tagged with flutter. flutter-widget is a subset of flutter with more specificity. It certainly does add useful information and a narrower scope to the question.

Yes there are other parts, but we also have the tag `flutter-layout` which can be used for any flutter widget issue like positioning, constraint, etc...

Comment: I can agree with this. Considering that there is the flutter-layout tag as well, this makes for a fair bit of overlap. Certainly there are flutter widgets that do not have anything to do with layout, and there may be layout issues that are not related to widgets, but the line has to be drawn somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with this proposal. While flutter has been marketed as "Everything's a widget", there are actually many parts of flutter development that are not related to widgets such as business logic, platform code and ffi, compilation targets, compilation modes, performance and observatory, testing. These are just a few off the top of my head. It is unsurprising that only four flutter-widget questions are not also tagged with flutter. flutter-widget is a subset of flutter with more specificity. It certainly does add useful information and a narrower scope to the question

---

This post is a copy of my comment on the original post. (I don't use meta much, so I was unfamiliar with how things normally work here)

Comment: The "flutter-widget" tag does not add any information, either way. Knowing that the person uses widgets in their Flutter app is of no value when trying to assess whether I can help with the question, because everybody does. Instead the post should be tagged with tags that *do* carry information. For example a *specific* widget (Button, ListView, etc) or a *specific* non widget problem (BLoC, APK, signatures, etc).

Comment: @Stephen if you filter the [list of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) on the word _flutter_ you will see there are a wide range.  Hopeful this will put your minds at rest.